# Can't import User32.dll into Visual Studio

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2012, user32

I tried:

- To add *user32.dll* from *Reference Manager*, and imported it from *Windows\System32\user32.dll*, I got **Error Message**:

  **A reference to 'C:\Windows\System32\user32.dll couldn't be added.
  Please make sure that the file is accessible, and that it is a valid assembly or COM component.**
- `using System.Runtime.InteropServices; [DllImport("user32")]`
- To launch Visual Studio as Administrator

Nothing works... it goes on my nerves I am trying 2 hours to import this damn .dll...

Comment: What is your actual goal of adding that DLL? You've mentioned `DllImport` which clearly doesn't need adding native DLL as reference...

Comment: @RohitVats: That question deals with .NET or COM DLLs, not plain Win32 DLLs like `user32.dll`.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You do not need to add a reference to User32.dll.  It is part of Windows and can be imported in your code without adding a reference. You do this using P/Invoke.

```
[System.Runtime.InteropServices.DllImport("user32.dll")]
public static extern void SetWindowText(int hWnd, String text);

private void button3_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    IntPtr wHnd = this.Handle;//assuming you are in a C# form application
    SetWindowText(wHnd.ToInt32(), "New Window Title");
}
```

See Also:

- [Using P/Invoke from MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/cc164123.aspx)
- [Calling API Functions](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/1285/Calling-API-functions-using-C)

Comment: Thank you! I didn't realize/know that method should be defined ( public static extern void SetWindowText(int hWnd, String text); )

Comment: Well it is not that method purely that needs to be defined.  Each method that you reference from `user32.dll` must be present in that format:

`[System.Runtime.InteropServices.DllImport("user32.dll")]`
`public static extern void <METHODNAME>(<PARAMS>);`

Answer (score 1):

It's not a .NET dll.  You don't "add reference" the same way you do with .NET dlls.  Instead you have to add P/Invoke code to your app to invoke the functions you want.  Here's a good resource for learning pinvoke:  http://pinvoke.net/